# How to use a variable from the url

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use a variable from the current url to calculate the number of the next page.

Here is my route:

```
@app.route('/feed')
@app.route('/feed/<int:page>')
@is_logged_in
def feed(page=0):
    my_feed = mongo.db.feed
    posts = my_feed.find({}).skip(50*page).limit(50)
    return render_template('feed.html', posts=posts)
```

and here is my template at the moment:

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('feed', page=page+1) }}">Next</a>
```

Obviously, `page=page+1` does not work, but it demonstrates what I am trying to do. All I need is a way to add 1 to the current page number, so that my next link will take the user to the next page. I tried using `request.args.get('page')`, but it returns `None`.

How can I get the current page number and use it in my `url_for` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously, `page=page+1` does not work

Yes, it would work just fine, provided you pass the `page` local variable to the template:

```
return render_template('feed.html', posts=posts, page=page)
```

But you can also access the route variables via the [`request.view_args` mapping](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.view_args):

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('feed', page=request.view_args['page'] + 1) }}">Next</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Martijn Pieters. I was missing the page variable in render_template as you pointed out.